Type error: Type 'SearchPageProps' does not satisfy the constraint 'PageProps' when building Next.js project
I'm working on a Next.js app and have a page component that takes in searchParams to handle search functionality. However, when I try to build the project with npm run build, I encounter the following error:
    Type error: Type 'SearchPageProps' does not satisfy the constraint 'PageProps'.
  Types of property 'searchParams' are incompatible.
    Type '{ term: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<any>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]

Here is the code for my SearchPage :
import Search from "@/components/common/search";
import DocsTable from "@/components/documents/doc-table";
import { fetchDocsBySearch } from "@/db/queries/docs";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

interface SearchPageProps {
    searchParams: {
        term: string;
    };
}

export default async function SearchPage({ searchParams }: SearchPageProps) {
    const { term } = await searchParams;
    if (!term) {
        redirect("/");
    }

    return (
        <div className="m-10 space-y-4">
            <h1>Documents</h1>

            <div className="w-1/4">
                <Search />
            </div>

            <DocsTable fetchData={() => fetchDocsBySearch(term)} />
        </div>
    );
}

It seems like Next.js is expecting searchParams to have a different type or expects it in a different way.
